# Camtasia on remote computer?

Tags: screen-capture

I have a need to use one laptop for a live presentation (with projector, etc.), but record that presentation on another laptop -- similar to what I can do with Camtasia, only with the recording happening on another laptop.

Is this possible?  What do I need to do this?  Some VGA device that goes between the presenting machine and the projector?  Some USB device?

My ideal requirements:

- The machines must be "standard" laptops (so I can't just add a new card to a desktop, etc.).
- I prefer a hardware solution, but cannot involve studio type equipment.
- I'd prefer not to install Camtasia (or similar) on the presenting machine for two reasons:

  - licensing issues
  - performance issues (sometimes the presentations are machine intensive and I don't want the recording software to interfere with the presentation)

I'd appreciate any tips.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one fallback option if you do not find what you are after would be [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) or another VNC product.

This would allow you to drive the remote computer for your presentation, then you can use Camtasia on your laptop to record the VNC screen display.

Granted this may not be a perfect solution, but at least it may just do what you require.

Comment: So you're suggesting that instead of "recording remotely" the presenter is "presenting remotely"?  I'll give that a test.  Thanks.  I'd still rather have some device, but I'm not sure what that would be without having a lot of equipment.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking into doing this, and infact have already done it using this method.

I would recommend using a Ethernet cable to do the communication, ideally gigabit which would help increase the throughput(it does make a difference).

This seems to me to be the simplest solution.

I would also recommend using Remote desktop over VNC as on windows Remote desktop performs better, but on linux/OSX VNC is better/the only choice.

Comment: >but on linux/OSX VNC is better/the only choice.

This is untrue. There is an RDP client for Mac OS made by Microsoft and there is a native RDP client built into most Linux distros. Now whether VNC is the better choice, I would say yes.